# <TextInput /> is not consistent with Component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a simple form in React Native. What I'm trying to do is that when the value of the input field changes, I want to update the state (`phone` in this case). The value of the input field always equals the value of a state. However, when the value of the input field changes, the value of the state(`phone`) is not updated. Thanks in advance. Here is the code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    padding: 5,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});

export default class AddContactForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    phone: 'sdfksd',
  };

  handlePhoneChange = (phone) => {
    this.setState({
      phone: '111',
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ paddingTop: 40 }}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.phone}
          onChangeText={this.handlePhoneChange}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          placeholder="Phone"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATED: Even though I set `phone` in `handlePhoneChange`, I still can update the text field to a different value apparently. That's inconsistent between the state and the text field.

Comment: Why are you setting phone to `111`? Do you want your text input to have the value of '111' no matter what a user enters?

Comment: Just put an update. Please at least think or try it first before commenting.

Comment: But when you type into the text field, it is still being changed even though the state is always `111`

Comment: @BillPham if you can change it to my answer your problem will be solved!

Answer (score -2):

onChangeText takes a callback.
So in your case pass the input to your function like this

```
onChangeText={ val => this.handlePhoneChange(val)}
```

Comment: Yes I did. It's a class method

Comment: well, yea I agree it's a class method. But you need to pass the value of onChangeText to your function. @BillPham

Comment: @BillPham No it's not. It's a function valued property. packability, he is passing the value but he's not using it in the implementation. I have no idea why but that would explain why it doesn't do anything

Comment: yea because onChangeText takes a callback. So even if he doesn't use the value the function will now be call and the state will be set with his  hardcoded value

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the bug. The bug was in the implementation of the function. It's a stupid bug it's a waste of time and the question should be closed as off topic due to a typo

Comment: Yeah I think it's a bug, when you write `handlePhoneChange` differently instead of setting the value `111` regardless of what user enters, there doesn't seem to be a problem. This question should be closed because I don't see a point in it and they should probably report this bug on Github

Comment: yea he didn't use the onChangeText correctly. @BillPham does it work for you?

Comment: what do you mean @BillPham?

Answer (score -2):

Change your handle function like this.

handlePhoneChange = (phone) => {
    this.setState({
      phone: phone
    })
  }